# How to save multiple items to localStorage in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, local-storage

I am having trouble saving multiple items to the DOM local storage. Everytime i add an item it saves it eprfectly well after page reload but when i add a new item it overwrites the previous one. How can i save every item i add to the localStorage?

JS

```
var prodname, prodprice, proddescript;
var savedContent = $('.container')        

var content = [];   


$('.addform').fadeOut(0);
    i = 0;
    $('.addproduct').click(function() {
    $('.addform').fadeIn(300);    
});    

$('.addtostore').click(function(e) {
    prodname = $('.prodname').val();
    prodprice = $('.prodprice').val();
    proddescript = $('.proddescript').val();
$('.container').append('<div class="prodcont"><img src="https://picsum.photos/20'+(++i)+'/300"/> 
    <h4>'+prodname+'</h4><p>$'+prodprice+'.00</p><span>'+proddescript+'</span><button>Add to 
     cart</button></div>');  
     content[i] = '<div class="prodcont"><img src="https://picsum.photos/20'+(++i)+'/300"/> 
     <h4>'+prodname+'</h4><p>$'+prodprice+'.00</p><span>'+proddescript+'</span><button>Add to 
     cart</button></div>'; 
      localStorage.setItem('content', JSON.stringify(content));
$('.addform').fadeOut(300);
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});


var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("content"));

savedContent.append(saved);
```

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Here's a link to download the project, so you can demo it and see the problem. To add products, just click the + button on the header nav bar.
Thanks!

Download Link: https://scorpionedge.com/version2/version2.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to my question is here.

For anyone needing the same solution.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/store-multiple-values-in-localstorage-apin-in-html-5

Answer (score 0):

There are mechanisms for browser local storage. If you want to store different data then every time you need to add different key for the store that data. **When you are trying to add new data it will search your given key in local storage if your given key found in storage then it will write data in that key.**

That's why every time you will get updated data on that key. Because the previous one was overwritten in local storage.

There are many ways for store data into the local storage.

1. If you check for that key before you saving data if key found then use another key.
2. You can try the below code.

> ```
> //Save the values to Localstorage
> localStorage.setItem('first','firstvalue');
> localStorage.setItem('second','secondvalue');
>
> //Retrieve the values from localstorage
> localStorage.getItem('first')
> //"firstvalue"
> localStorage.getItem('second')
> //"secondvalue"
> ```

Comment: I know why its overwriting it. I udnersood this, i was hoping for a solution actually on how to achieve what i want.